# Maintain URL state while navigation to different component in Vite React TS Application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

**Expected Behavior**

1. When navigating to a different component or route within the React SPA, the base path should remain intact in the URL.
2. Any links or routes defined within the application should be relative to the base path, ensuring that the user can access different sections of the SPA without encountering broken links or routing issues.
3. The navigation should not strip or lose the base path, and the URLs should reflect the correct structure of the SPA.
   For example, if the base path is set to "/queryhubadmin" and there is a route defined for a component "dashboard," the expected URL should be "https://localhost:3000/queryhubadmin/queries" when navigating to the dashboard component.

**Actual Behavior**
On navigating to Queries list page, the url generated is https://localhost:3000/queries, which on refresh breaks the application flow.

App.tsx

```
import "./App.css";
import QueryTable from "./Components/QueryTable";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import CreateQuery from "./Components/CreateQuery";
import { FluentProvider, teamsLightTheme } from "@fluentui/react-components";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  HashRouter,
  MemoryRouter,
  Navigate,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import ViewQuery from "./Components/ViewQuery";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Components/auth/ProtectedRoute";
import BreadCrumbs from "./Components/BreadCrumbs";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: Infinity,
      cacheTime: Infinity,
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const { isLoading, loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && !isAuthenticated) {
      loginWithRedirect();
    }
  }, [isLoading, isAuthenticated]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <FluentProvider theme={teamsLightTheme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Header isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />
          <BreadCrumbs />
          <div className="main">
            <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />
            <div className="content">
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/queries" />} />
                <Route path="/queries" element={<QueryTable />} />
                <Route path="/queries/create" element={<CreateQuery />} />
                <Route path="/queries/:id" element={<ViewQuery />} />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </FluentProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/queryhubadmin",
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    https: {
      cert: "./certs/certificate.pem",
      key: "./certs/key.pem",
    },
  },
});
```

Sidebar/index.tsx

```
import {
  Drawer,
  DrawerBody,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerHeaderTitle,
} from "@fluentui/react-components/unstable";
import "./index.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

interface SidebarProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

function Sidebar({ isOpen, setIsOpen }: SidebarProps) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { logout } = useAuth0();

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Drawer
        type="inline"
        separator
        open={isOpen}
        onOpenChange={(_, { open }) => setIsOpen(open)}
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
      >
        <DrawerHeader>
          <DrawerHeaderTitle className="drawer-header"></DrawerHeaderTitle>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <DrawerBody className="body">
          <div>
            <a
              onClick={() => {
                navigate(`queries`, { state: history.state, replace: false });
                setIsOpen(!isOpen);
              }}
            >
              Queries
            </a>
            <hr />
            <a
              onClick={() => {
                setIsOpen(!isOpen);
                logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: "/" } });
              }}
            >
              Logout
            </a>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </DrawerBody>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

auth/ProtectedRoute.tsx

```
import { WithAuth0Props, withAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import { Routes } from "react-router";

interface ProtectedRouteProps extends WithAuth0Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const ProtectedRoute: FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ auth0, children }) => {
  if (auth0.isAuthenticated) {
   
    return  <Routes >{children}</Routes>;
  }
};

export default withAuth0(ProtectedRoute);
```

Here when I click on sidebar queries link to go to QueryTable component. The url changes to "https://localhost:3000/queries" it replaces the queryhubadmin to queries. I want it to change to "https://localhost:3000/queryhubadmin/queries".

I am new to using React Router go if you see any bad practices i would really appreciate improvement suggestions. If you require more information. Please comment.

I tried using HashRouter and it works. But I don't think using HashRouter is the best solution to this problem. And also it makes the url ugly with # appended to it.

MemoryRouter also works but it doesnt make any changes to URL.